# SELECT y UPDATE afectan a distinto número de rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, update

la consulta es fácil, como dice el título tengo distintos resultados en dos consultas super simples y no se porqué puede ser. Las consultas son:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Piezas WHERE idFabricante=2
```

Esta consulta me muestra 1454 registros cuyo idPieza es 2
Ahora quiero actualizar las notas de estos registros y añadirles "Actualizada" al final, para lo que uso la siguiente consulta:

```sql
UPDATE piezas SET notas=CONCAT(notas, ". Actualizado") WHERE idFabricante=2
```

Sin embargo esta consulta afecta a 224 registros únicamente.

Encuanto al tipo de datos Notas es `Text`, e IdFabricante `Int`

He estado mirando y esto suele ocurrir en casos con varias tablas y demás, pero como podréis comprobar son dos consultas muy sencillas por lo que entiendo que algo se me escapa.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Trabajamos en MySQL

La pregunta es ¿Por qué no afecta a todos los registros cuyo IdFabricante es 2?

---

Edito:
Estructura de la tabla:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `piezas` (
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idFabricante` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `notas` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=96875 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Datos de muestra:

```sql
INSERT INTO `piezas` VALUES ('2015-06-11 12:51:23','2015-06-11 12:51:23',103,4,NULL), ('2015-06-11 12:51:23','2015-06-11 12:51:23',104,2,'Grande'), ('2015-06-11 12:51:23','2015-06-11 12:51:23',105,4,'Pequeño'), ('2015-06-11 12:51:23','2015-06-11 12:51:23',106,4,'Mediano'), ('2015-06-11 12:51:23','2015-06-11 12:51:23',107,2,'Grande'), ('2015-06-11 12:51:23','2015-06-11 12:51:23',108,2,'Pequeño')
```

---

Edito:
A petición de Alfabravo realizo esta consulta:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Piezas WHERE idFabricante=2
```

Esta consulta me devuelve 1454 también.

Comment: `UPDATE Piezas`?

Comment: Sí perdón, cosa del copia-pega @DavidSilva

Comment: Por favor, estructura de la tabla y datos de muestra para entender cómo actúa la sentencia UPDATE.

Comment: @Alfabravo Añadido

Comment: ¿QUé tan frecuente crees que sea el caso del registro 103, que tiene la nota en NULL?

Comment: has probado a hace un set sin concat?

Comment: todos los registros del select tienen notas? cambia ese null por un '', ya que son diferente tipo de datos, y si mal no recuerdo y dependiendo del gestor de base de datos, no puedes concatenar un texto con un null

Comment: @Alfabravo bastante frecuente, de hecho al principio lo atribuí a eso, pero haciendo pruebas me di cuenta de que la sentencia afecta a registros con notas en null y con notas escritas, del mismo modo que no afecta a registros de ambos casos, luego descarto el que tenga que ver con eso.

Comment: @GDP he probado a cambiar las notas simplemente por "patata" y sigue afectando sólo a esos 224 registros. Por lo que descarto que sea culpa del CONCAT también :(

Comment: Perdón por ser desconfiado pero es sólo para ver bien. Haz un select count(*) sobre piezas donde idFabricante=2 y añade el resultado a tu pregunta.

Comment: Pregunta tonta, ¿y actualizar notas con cualquier valor tampoco afecta a todas las filas?

Comment: @Alfabravo añadido, pero da el resultado "bueno".

Comment: @David si no añado la cláusula WHERE afecta a todas las columnas de la tabla sin discriminar... Andarán por ahí los tiros... Ya no se que pensar

Comment: ¿La tabla tiene algún `trigger`?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ni disparadores, ni rutinas, ni eventos... El usuario con el que realizo las consultas es el administrador...

Comment: @Guillem yo creo que tiran por allí las cosas, y como todo el mundo esta comentando, el problema estara con los null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente he conseguido hacer una consulta que afecta a todos los registros, ha sido la siguiente:

```sql
UPDATE piezas LEFT JOIN fabricantes ON piezas.idFabricante = fabricantes.id SET piezas.notas=Concat(piezas.notas, '. Actualizado') WHERE fabricantes.id=2
```

Esta consulta, haciendo el LEFT JOIN sí me da el resultado deseado, no tengo muy claro por qué así sí ha funcionado.

Es más, tras esto he probado a realizar la consulta anterior (sin el `JOIN`) y ha afectado a todos los registros, es decir, a los 1454 registros.

Sí que es cierto que ya no había campos con el valor `notas` en `NULL`, pero aun así de haber sido el problema el tema de los nulls, la consulta que al final ha funcionado no lo hubiera hecho igualmente. Además de que habían registros que sí contenían notas y no se actualizaban.

Pese a que ha funcionado, sigo en busca de la explicación/solución y seguiré comprobando en una base de datos de respaldo vuestras ideas, por si alguien se anima a ello ya que me tiene muy intrigado este tema. Yo seguiré haciendo pruebas y en caso de llegar a alguna conclusión lo añadiré a esta respuesta.

Muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: El left join incluye resultados Null, si pones un Inner no te va a pasar lo mismo. De todas formas, con un left join obtendras mas resultados que con una sola tabla porque lo que haces es fusionar todos los resultados posibles con la tabla de la izquierda, incluidos null.

Comment: esto no es correcto del todo. Espero no sean datos importantes. lo que tienes que hacer es un IFNULL(expression, alt_value) dentro de tu update

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación de la función Concat()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat): si algún valor es NULL, el resultado es NULL.

Según la [documentación de UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html). Se retorna el número de filas que fueron modificadas.

Entonces:

- Según 1 podémos determinar que los registros que tengan NULL en la columna notas retornarán NULL en la función concat y no sería necesario modificar el dato.
- Según 2 (esta interpretación es mía basada en la documentación y en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236501/mysql-determine-if-update-found-row-even-if-not-changed) las columnas que no se modificarón por la causa del punto 1, no se incluyen en el resultado de columnas modificadas.

Para asegurarte de que se modifique el registro, podés convertir la columna con valor NULL a un string vacío utilizando la función COALESCE(...).

```
notas = Concat(Coalesce(notas, ''), '. Actualizado')
```

Otro problema podría ser que estás utilizando comillas dobles en el update en lugar de comillas simples para definir un string. Cambiar **". Actualizado"** por **'. Actualizado'**.

Comment: El lunes lo pruebo, probablemente sea parte del problema. Aún así quedan columnas cuyo valor en Notas no es NULL y que no se actualizan... Gracias, te mantendré informado.

Answer (score 0):

¿Estas usando un SO Unix? Segun parece para ciertas distribuciones los nombres de las tablas distinguen mayusculas de minusculas en MySql, y tu `SELECT` lo haces a 'Piezas' mientras que tu `UPDATE` lo estas haciendo a 'piezas'

En el siguiente enlace puedes verlo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive

Comment: No, está en un Windows Server. De todos modos el problema de Mayus/Minus ya lo he probado y en este caso no afecta. Gracias de todos modos.

Answer (score -1):

Efectivamente, UPDATE sólo te notifica el número de filas actualizadas. Si no ha podido actualizarlas o se quedan con el mismo valor, no las contabiliza.

En tu dataset tienes registros en los que que el campo `notas` vale `NULL`. En esos casos, aunque hagas un `CONCAT` para añadir algo más, el resultado sigue siendo `NULL` (cualquier valor operado con `NULL` resulta `NULL`), por lo que esos registros no son modificados y, en consecuencia, no se contabilizan como modificados.

Espero haberte respondido.

Comment: Lo se, pero la pregunta es por qué no actualiza todos, los 1454.

Comment: Ya entiendo tu duda, modifico la respuesta para aclarártela. Saludos.

Comment: Sí, eso que dices es cierto, pero utilizando lo que comenta Damián Alva en la respuesta anterior sigue ocurriendo lo mismo. Además de que pese a que la afirmación es correcta, hay registros que sí tienen un valor en el campo notas y no se ven afectadas por la consulta... Gracias de todos modos ;)

Comment: Pues vaya misterio. ¿En el dataset que nos has pasado también sucede esto? Añade los registros que no se actualizan y, a ver si reproduciendo el caso, conseguimos encontrar una solución.